# How to determine the ON clause for a dynamic query using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a script that will allow the user to select a list of fields to be displayed from different column/table in a database. This script will need be able to generate the full query and execute it.

I am able to select the field and add the proper where clause. However, I am being challenged on how to generate the `ON` clause which is part of the `JOIN` statement.

Here is what I have done so far. 
First, I defined 3 tables like so

```
-- list of all tables available in the database
CREATE TABLE `entity_objects` (
  `object_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `object_name` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `object_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- list of all tables available in the database
CREATE TABLE `entity_definitions` (
  `entity_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `display_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `entity_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `entity_type` enum('lookup','Integer','text','datetime','date') CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `object_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `object_id` (`object_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- a list of the fields that are related to each other. For example entity 12 is a foreign key to entity 11.
CREATE TABLE `entity_relations` (
  `relation_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_a` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `entity_b` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `relation_type` enum('1:1','1:N') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1:1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`relation_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `entity_a` (`entity_a`,`entity_b`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

To get a list of the relations that are available, I run this query

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT(oa.object_name, '.', ta.entity_key) AS entityA
,  CONCAT(ob.object_name, '.', tb.entity_key) AS entityB
FROM entity_relations as r
INNER JOIN entity_definitions AS ta ON ta.entity_id = r.entity_a
INNER JOIN entity_definitions AS tb ON tb.entity_id = r.entity_b
INNER JOIN entity_objects AS oa ON oa.object_id = ta.object_id
INNER JOIN entity_objects AS ob ON ob.object_id = tb.object_id
```

I am having hard time trying to figure out how to generated the `JOIN` statement of the query. I am able to generate the `SELECT .....` and the `WHERE...` but need help trying to generate the `ON....` part of the query.

My final query should look something like this

```
SELECT 
  accounts.account_name
, accounts.industry_id
, accounts.primary_number_id
, accounts.person_id
, industries.industry_id
, industries.name
, contact_personal.first_name
, contact_personal.person_id
, account_phone_number.number_id
FROM accounts 
LEFT JOIN industries ON industries.industry_id = accounts.industry_id
LEFT JOIN contact_personal ON contact_personal.person_id = accounts.person_id
LEFT JOIN account_phone_number ON account_phone_number.number_id = accounts.primary_number_id
WHERE industries.name = 'Marketing'
```

I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2a6e/2) with my MySQL code.

How can I define the `ON` clause of the join statement correctly?

Comment: what is dynamic about your join conditions? are you looking for something hierarchical? ie entity_relation joining to entity_relation multiple times?

Comment: May be hierarchical is a better term to use. I want to be able to add ad much joining as needed to give the user the data he/she are looking for.

Comment: Can't you just use PHP for this? I am assuming the first query will get all your relations and then the user indicates which data they would like to be displayed, so just do something like `if (isDisplayed('industries.name')) { $query .= "LEFT JOIN industries ON industries.industry_id = accounts.industry_id"; }`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: fyi, your final query doesn't use any of the tables in the question. but what you're asking for is dynamically determine entity -> entity_relationship.entity_a -> entity_relationship.entity_b -> entity_relationship.entity_a ... N ?

Comment: @pala_ I am assuming the tables/columns all come from the result of the first `SELECT`.

Comment: @Mike, yes I can use PHP for this. I just don't know which relation to use the user can pick fields from many tables.

Comment: @pala_ Interesting... two Mikes here. I wonder who gets pinged if you ping one of us.

Comment: @Mike But if the user can pick which fields to show, those are the ones you need to include. I must not be understanding something correctly. Perhaps it might help if you provide a bit of data and a sample request and desired result.

Comment: @Mike please look at the fiddle as I have some sample data of the tables that I posted in my question. What I am not sure on how to do is narrowing down which relation to pick from the relations table. There could be multiple relations that belong to the same table . In my example above, I start with the `accounts` table but what if the user did not pick anything for the accounts table?

Comment: @Mike This is just horrendously confusing.

Comment: @pala_ haha I got that ping.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely unnecessary to create these tables, mysql can handle all of this for you so long as you are using the InnoDB storage engine by using foreign keys.

> list all tables on current database

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

> get list of columns on a given table

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = :schema
    AND TABLE_NAME = :table;
```

> get list of relationships between tables

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
INNER JOIN
    information_schema.INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN isf ON
        isf.ID = concat(tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, '/', tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME)
INNER JOIN
    information_schema.INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS isfc ON
        isfc.ID = isf.ID
WHERE
    tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = :schema
    AND tc.TABLE_NAME = :table;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. The main reason why I use my own tables is because I have custom fields where I store custom information as objects. so I will need a table to keep up with all that custom object/fields that I have setup. Also, using the MySQL table will create an overhead on the system which will decrease performance. I was advised my Oracle engineer to never use MySQL table for the use in my Application. I also forgot to mention that I don't have any constrains setup in my tables so MySQL will not know the relation between the foreign keys.

Comment: so then would it not make sense to just store the information about the custom fields? You could always run a cron job or a manual run script that will extract the information from those tables and cache them onto your own tables, should you not want to query the information_schema table directly.

Comment: possible, but again, I don't have foreign key constrain setup so that query you listed will not give m anything. Adding constrains will increase the dead locks and my not be a good idea for a busy database

Comment: not sure how adding foreign key constraints would cause deadlock situations. foreign keys are a good thing, they will actually help improve the quality of your database by prevented orphaned data. They could also be used to restrict the deletion of data as well.

Comment: I meant to write locks not dead locks. when constrains are added, there will be an additional operation to the foreign table